# Dimension of the fibre product of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mu : X \to Y$ be a morphism of algebraic varieties. Suppose that both $X$ and $Y$ are of pure dimension $x$ and $y$, respectively. Under what assumptions can we conclude that the fibre product $X \times_Y X$ is of pure dimension $\dim X \times_Y X = 2x - y$?

Comment: What kind of assumptions are you looking for? There are a number of ways this can go wrong and a number of ways it can go right. So, a reasonable answer would depend on what you are looking for.

Comment: @Mohan I guess the weakest/most general assumptions would be the most interesting. I was originally thinking about semismall maps, in which case $\dim X \times_Y X = \dim X$. There one has a decomposition of $Y$ into locally closed subvarities over which $\mu$ is a locally trivial fibration, so one can compute dimension of the fibre product easily by considering the preimage of an open stratum. So to some extent my motivation was to see what can make semismallness go right/wrong.